# Why does using a DrawerLayout give IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout

The following is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tailamade.boop.CustomerHomeActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_customer_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_main"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_customer_home" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

I have also tried writing my own CustomDrawerLayout like so (with no luck):

```
class CustomDrawerLayout : DrawerLayout {

constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
    var widthMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec
    var heightMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
}
```

}

I have seen other posts regarding this exception but the "solutions" do not work. Whats the issue here?

Comment: What version of the support library are you using?

Comment: Posting for reference: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/407e01608ccafe5dc24f82608583f71c34312f9c/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java#626 Not sure what version of the library that corresponds to though.

Comment: @stkent support library version 26.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The width needs to be specified in dpi, not "wrap_content"(see [navigation drawer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#Init))

> •The drawer view specifies its width in dp units and the height matches the parent view. The drawer width should be no more than 320dp so the user can always see a portion of the main content

**EDIT** As far as your child class goes, does it give the same error?  I am guessing that when the "wrap_content" size is computed, that the actual width is not valid (perhaps zero).  You should check the width in onMeasure and make sure it is within limits (greater than zero, substantially less than the parent width so that it can still be seen when drawer is open).